# Drawing in custom UIView wrongly placed in iOS7 but correct in iOS8

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm drawing rings and circles in a custom view of mine. While this works perfectly well in iOS8, in iOS7 the drawing is done on totally different origins. What am I missing here?

Displayed correctly in iOS8:

[image: iOS8]

Displayed incorrectly in iOS7:

[image]

Offscreen rendering shows me, that iOS7 recognizes my frames correctly:

[image]

How I calculate the **arcCenter** and **arcRadius**:

```
func prepareLayerAndShape()
{
    let size = self.frame.size.height >= self.frame.size.width ? self.frame.size.width : self.frame.size.height
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2
    self.arcRadius = size / 2
    self.arcCenter = CGPointMake(size / 2, size / 2)
}
```

The drawing done in **drawRect**:

```
func createBackgroundRing(graphicsContext: CGContext)
{
    CGContextBeginPath(graphicsContext)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(graphicsContext, self.delegate.shapeBackgroundColor(self))
    CGContextAddArc(graphicsContext, self.arcCenter.x, self.arcCenter.y, self.arcRadius - self.delegate.ringLineWidth(self) / 2, 0.0, CGFloat(2 * M_PI), 1)
    CGContextStrokePath(graphicsContext)
}

func createCountdownRing(graphicsContext: CGContext)
{
    CGContextBeginPath(graphicsContext)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(graphicsContext, self.delegate.shapeForegroundColor(self))
    CGContextAddArc(graphicsContext, self.arcCenter.x, self.arcCenter.y, self.arcRadius - self.delegate.ringLineWidth(self) / 2, self.startAngle, self.endAngle, self.delegate.isClockwise(self))
    CGContextStrokePath(graphicsContext)
}
```

The calculation of the position and size of the frames for my custom views done in the ViewController:

```
func frameForPosition(position: CGFloat) -> CGRect
{
    let displacementFact: CGFloat = 1.5
    let cWidth = self.viewCountdown.frame.size.width
    let cHeight = self.viewCountdown.frame.size.height
    let diff = cWidth > cHeight ? cWidth - cHeight : cHeight - cWidth
    let size = cWidth > cHeight ? cHeight : cWidth
    let x = cWidth > cHeight ? self.viewCountdown.frame.origin.x + diff / 2 : self.viewCountdown.frame.origin.x
    let y = cHeight > cWidth ? self.viewCountdown.frame.origin.y  + diff / 2 : self.viewCountdown.frame.origin.y

    let countDownRingFrame = CGRectMake(
        x + displacementFact * self.lineWidth * position,
        y + displacementFact * self.lineWidth * position,
        size - (displacementFact * 2.0 * self.lineWidth * position),
        size - (displacementFact * 2.0 * self.lineWidth * position)
    )

    return countDownRingFrame
}
```

Side note: I started coding the project for iOS8 but had to downgrade to iOS7 afterwards.

Comment: What is shapeBackgroundColor?

Comment: This might not be very helpful, but I would start by `NSLog`ging all the variables in both iOS 7 and iOS 8 simulators to check for any difference that could explain some misplacements.

Comment: I have done that and there a no differences... :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by deleting the ViewController in the Storyboard and the file itself and adding them both again. Apparently the downgrading was the source of the problem. The same code works just fine now.